# React Error Boundary does not catch errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, vite, react-error-boundary

I have my react app created from `vite` and there I have my Custom React Error Boundary Component wrap from Components the thing is it cannot catch errors.i debug my error component but it cannot recieve any value in `getDerivedStateFromError` not `componentDidCatch`

Here is my Error Boundary Code:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
import React, { Component } from 'react';

interface IState {
  hasError: boolean;
  eventId?: string;
}

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
interface IProps {
  children: any;
}

export default class ErrorBoundary extends Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: Readonly<{}>) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { eventId: '', hasError: false };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error: any) {
    console.log('here get Derived');
    // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error: any, errorInfo: any) {
    console.log('My errors', error);
  
  }

  render() {
    // const { children } = this.props;
    console.log('errors');
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      console.log('errors found', this.state.hasError);
      return (
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            console.log("Error Found)
          }
        >
          Report feedback
        </button>
      );
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

and my app.js code:

```
import './App.css';
function App() {


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              throw new Error('Im new Error');
            }}
          >
            Click Me
          </button>
        </ErrorBoundary>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

does anyone knows what is the issue ?

Comment: Check my question and you will find out the answer. My question is linked with yours.

Answer (score 2):

Error boundaries do not catch errors for:

- Event handlers
- Asynchronous code (e.g. setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame
  callbacks)
- Server side rendering
- Errors thrown in the error boundary itself
  (rather than its children)

https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#introducing-error-boundaries

To simulate an error, you need to create a component, make it a child of ErrorBoundary class and click on the button 2 times

```
   function Button() {
    
      const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
      const onClick = () => {
        setCount(count + 1);
      };
      useEffect(() => {
        if (count === 2) {
          throw new Error('I crashed!');
        }
      });
        
      return (
          <button
              onClick={onClick}
           >
              Click Me
           </button>
       );
    }
        
    export default Button;
```

Comment: Hi. This answer and the reference link are useful.  The "To simulate an error" part is confusing. Remove it and I'll be happy to up-vote your answer. But note that the link should be updated to a page on https://react.dev, since reactjs.org is deprecated now.